# How to copy a value from one row to another based on a column value in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame which looks like the following

```
Order Location 
1     X
1     NA
2     Y
2     Y
2     NA
3     Z
3     NA
4     Z
```

I want to replace the NA in column Location with locations pertaining to the same order number. The final result should be

```
Order Location 
1     X
1     X
2     Y
2     Y
2     Y
3     Z
3     Z
4     Z
```

How do I achieve this in R using dplyr or any other packages?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    fill(Location)
```

---

If it needs to be grouped by 'Order'

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(Order) %>%
   fill(Location)
```